# Class Inheritance, ENUM issues with AST class implementations

Tags: c++, inheritance, enums, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm currently working on a compiler project with the toy-language Micro, implemented using Bison with C++.  I've created some classes to deal with building the AST to evaluate expressions, and was trying to implement this with inheritance.  I have a parent class ASTNode, which I would like to define child classes like AddExprNode, shown below.

I'm specifically having issues using the enum (ASTNodeType) from my ASTNode.hpp in my child class, and am receiving an issue regarding the class-name.  I've been trying to research these on my own but have had a lot of trouble.

Why can't the g++ find the class-name, and why doesn't it know that ASTNodeType has been declared?  Here are the errors I'm receiving, followed by my code.

Errors:

```
In file included from src/AddExprNode.cpp:3:
src/AddExprNode.hpp:13: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
src/AddExprNode.hpp:18: error: ‘ASTNodeType’ has not been declared
src/AddExprNode.cpp:8: error: ‘ASTNodeType’ has not been declared
src/AddExprNode.cpp: In constructor ‘AddExprNode::AddExprNode(std::string,     int)’:
src/AddExprNode.cpp:8: error: ‘ASTNode’ has not been declared
src/AddExprNode.cpp:8: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘ASTNode’
src/AddExprNode.cpp: At global scope:
src/AddExprNode.cpp:8: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
```

ASTNode.hpp:

```
#include <string>

enum class ASTNodeType
{
    UNDEFINED,
    ADD_EXPR,
    MULT_EXPR,
    VAR_REF
};

class ASTNode
{
    public:
        ASTNodeType Type;
        ASTNode * Left;
        ASTNode * Right;

        ASTNode();
        ASTNode(ASTNodeType type);

        void setType(ASTNodeType Type);
        void setLeftChild(ASTNode * Left);
        void setRightChild(ASTNode * Right);

    private:

};
```

ASTNode.cpp:

```
#ifndef AST_H
#define AST_H
#include "ASTNode.hpp"
#endif

ASTNode::ASTNode(ASTNodeType type)
{
    Type = type;
    Left = NULL;
    Right = NULL;
}

ASTNode::ASTNode()
{
    Type = ASTNodeType::UNDEFINED;
    Left = NULL;
    Right = NULL;
}

void ASTNode::setType(ASTNodeType Type)
{
    Type = Type;
}

void ASTNode::setLeftChild(ASTNode * Left)
{
    Left = Left;
}

void ASTNode::setRightChild(ASTNode * Right)
{
    Right = Right;
}
```

AddExprNode.hpp:

```
#ifndef AST_H
#define AST_H
#include "ASTNode.hpp"
#endif

#include <string>

class AddExprNode : public ASTNode
{
    public:
        std::string add_op;

        //AddExprNode() : ASTNode(){};
        AddExprNode(std::string inputOp, ASTNodeType type);

        std::string getOp();
};
```

AddExprNode.cpp:

```
#ifndef AST_H
#define AST_H
#include "AddExprNode.hpp"
#endif

#include <string>

AddExprNode::AddExprNode(std::string inputOp, ASTNodeType type) : ASTNode::ASTNode(type){
    add_op = inputOp;
    //Type = type;
}

std::string AddExprNode::AddExprNode::getOp(){
    return add_op;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not using include guards properly.  The define for the guard belongs in the .h file, not the file that includes it.

AddExprNode.cpp defines the `AST_H` symbol.  AddExprNode.hpp sees that the symbol is already defined, so it does *not* include ASTNode.hpp.  This results in `ASTNodeType` not being defined when you go to use it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Now that I understand header guards better, I've been able to smoothly use that throughout all the linked class implementations/inclusions.  Cheers!